# Why the scripts gives me this error: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'bytearray'

Tags: python, error-handling

Thank you all for the help, i didnt see that dati was getting fed a bytearray instead of a decoded line

Comment: How do you call the function? If `n` is a bytearray, the error makes sense, if not please provide enough details to reproduce the problem

Comment: msg_len = recvall(sckt, 4) this is how its called

Comment: I think you missed the "*if not please provide enough details to reproduce the problem*" part ;)

Comment: i was editing the question

Comment: ``recvall(sckt, msg_len)`` passes a bytearray (``msg_len``) as the second argument. You probably should have passed the unpacked ``msg`` instead.

Comment: `msg_len = recvall(sckt, 4)` here msg_len is a byte so when you pass it in line `return recvall(sckt, msg_len)`, the function compares it with an int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line `return recvall(sckt, msg_len)` might be causing the issue.

Here `msg_len` is `msg_len = recvall(sckt, 4)` so a `bytearray` type as `recvall` returns `dati`, that is `dati = bytearray()`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in here:

```
return recvall(sckt, msg_len)
```

Here, you are using msg_len, which from the code we get:

```
msg_len = recvall(sckt, 4)
```

Looking the type of the return of this function:

```
return dati
```

which is a byte array, thus your msg_len isn't the message length, but the byte array. I suspect you might want to do something such as len(msg_len), but I can't say for sure. But that's the source of your issue.